# Finding all duplicate rows with the given conditions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table called Fruit which has two columns (id,cost) and I want to select id and cost, and find all duplicate rows where the cost is the same but the id is different. How can I write this query?

I write this query

```
SELECT id,cost
From Fruit a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Fruit b 
       WHERE a.cost = b.cost
) > 1
```

This works but only give me the rows where the cost is the same but the id might be same as well, **I only want results where the cost is the same but id is different**

Comment: Did you try adding `a.id != b.id` to the inner where clause?

Comment: Madhusudna this is sql so the operator not equal is shown by <>. You can not use !=.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1.*
FROM Fruit F1
INNER JOIN Fruit F2 ON F1.id <> F2.id AND F1.cost = F2.cost
```

If you want repeated id-cost pairs to be listed too, just remove the `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

you could select all the rows  with cost duplicated using a group by and having ccount(*) >1

and for this get all the row that match

```
  select a.id, a.cost
  from Fruit a
  where cost in ( select b.cost 
   from  fruit b
   group by b.cost 
   having count(*) > 1
  )
```

for avoid duplicated  result you can add distinct

```
  select distinct a.id, a.cost
  from Fruit a
  where cost in ( select b.cost 
   from  fruit b
   group by b.cost 
   having count(*) > 1
  )
```

Comment: What about if the id is the same, then I will get those rows as well, I am unsure how to select same cost but different id using this syntax

Comment: That returns results with repeated ids, which is not what @spyang302 needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple condition where id are not equal.

> SELECT id,cost From Fruit a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fruit b WHERE a.cost = b.cost and a.id <> b.id ) > 1

Here **<>** is operator for **not equal**.
I hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work in the where clause

Comment: This doesn't work. You should actually do `> 0`. And optionally add a `DISTINCT` in the main `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple condition where id are not equal.

> SELECT id,cost From Fruit a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fruit b WHERE a.cost = b.cost and a.id <> b.id ) > 1

Here **<>** is the operator Of **not equal** in sql.

Comment: Prateek, you posted the same answer twice.

Answer (score -1):

This works. Ran it in SQL Server because Oracle is broken on Fiddle, but should work on either system.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ab
    ([id] int, [cost] int)
;

INSERT INTO ab
    ([id], [cost])
VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 15),
    (3, 15),
    (4, 24),
    (5, 68),
    (6, 13),
    (7, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with a1 as (
SELECT id
,cost
,rank () over (partition by cost order by id) dup
From ab
  )

  select * from a1 where dup > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/964142/6/01/0)**:

```
| id | cost | dup |
|----|------|-----|
|  2 |    5 |   2 |
```

And then to return all values where there was a duplicate cost:

```
with a1 as (
SELECT id
,cost
,rank () over (partition by cost order by id) dup
From ab
  )

,a2 as ( select * from a1 where dup > 1)

select * from ab
join a2 on ab.cost = a2.cost
```

Comment: spyang302 needs to get 1-5 and 2-5, not 3-15, which has the same id in both records.

Comment: oops, good point. I changed to rank which will return the duplicate value for 1-5, 2-5. If you are using this query to remove duplicates, that should work. If you need to return both values you could join this back to the dataset on  cost where dup = 2. I'll include that above.